# bytearray reference vs value type?

Tags: python, arrays, pass-by-reference

In Python, when a bytearray is passed to a function is it passed by reference or value?

In Python 3.7 i'm trying to mock the HTTPResponse object for testing.  When I copy the the code from inside the http.client.HTTPResponse object I get a different result than the than the standard library gets.

**My Code:**

```
#I call the mock buffer like this
intBytesBuffered = self.HTTPResponseMock.readinto(tempBuffer)
```

HTTPResponseMock

```
def read(self, amt = None):

    if amt is not None:
        # Amount is given, implement using readinto
        b = bytearray(amt)
    else:
        b = bytearray(len(self.MockedContentBuffer))

    n = self.readinto(b)
    return memoryview(b)[:n].tobytes()

def readinto(self, b):
    """docstring"""

    #mvb = memoryview(b)
    bufferSize = len(b)
    contentSize = len(self.MockedContentBuffer)
    b.clear()
    if bufferSize >= contentSize:
        b = self.MockedContentBuffer
    else:
        b = self.MockedContentBuffer[0:bufferSize]
        del self.MockedContentBuffer[0:bufferSize]

    return len(b)
```

Relevent functions from http.client.HTTPResponse are found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/http/client.py) lines 436-500

The most important excerpt from the standard library is here where read calls readinto:

```
b = bytearray(amt)
n = self.readinto(b)
return memoryview(b)[:n].tobytes()
```

The standard library is doing pretty much the same thing in calling the buffer as I am but when its run the bytearrary `b` in the excerpt returns with data inside it.  When I call read, `tempBuffer` returns empty?

Comment: In the shown code, `read` is never called and `limitBuffer` doesn't appear.

Comment: The problem lies in `readinto`: `b` contains a reference which is overwritten when a new value is assigned to `b`. The new reference is not returned or otherwise handed out at the end of `readinto`.

Comment: Python only ever puts heap references on the stack. You can't pass arrays by value like in C.

Comment: @gilch: You can pass arrays by value in C? That's news to me... Pretty sure you can't pass *arrays* at all (since they just degrade to pointers to the array). I'll note that Python's immutable types *behave* as if passed by value, which is usually close enough.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Arrays can live on the stack in C (not just the heap). To pass it by value you just have to wrap it in a struct. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-array-value-c/